# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Identity + React + Google Authentication - Failed to fetch (because of redirection?)

Tags: .net, reactjs, asp.net-core

I use ASP.NET Core 3.1 Identity to authenticate my users with JwtBearer. For front-end I use react app. For authentication I use *SignInManager* then I create Security token that I pass to react app. Everything work fine. 
Now I wanted to add also Google authentication. I follow kudvenkat with his tutorials.
https://youtu.be/ZgPK51X5BGw From 104 to 107. I know he is using Razor pages for front-end but I want to use this with react. My back-end is working fine.. also when I call Authenticate from browser like this it works fine. And I can get token in my browser.

```
https://localhost:44309/api/appusers/authenticate/Google
```

But problem is that I need to call Authenticate from react and then fetch token.

```
function loginExt(provider, returnUrl) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'Get',
    };

    return fetch('api/AppUsers/authenticate/' + provider, requestOptions)
        .then(handleResponse)
        .then(user => {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
            return user;
        }).catch(function (error) {
             console.log(error);
        });
}
```

But when I use ChallengeResult my call is redirected and probably react doesnt know what to do with that. 
Now I am just getting "TypeError: Failed to fetch".. any help how to call it from react??

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("authenticate/{provider}/{returnUrl?}")]
    public IActionResult Authenticate(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        try
        {
            var redirectUrl = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl) ? Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "AppUsers") : Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "AppUsers", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }


        [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("ExternalLoginCallback")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            return BadRequest(new { message = remoteError });
        }

        // Get the login information about the user from the external login provider
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(new { message = info });
        }

        // If the user already has a login (i.e if there is a record in AspNetUserLogins
        // table) then sign-in the user with this external login provider
        var signInResult = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider,
            info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

        if (signInResult.Succeeded)
        {
            var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            if (email != null)
            {
                var user = await _context.Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role).FirstOrDefaultAsync(w => w.NormalizedEmail == email.ToUpper());
                return ReturnJwtToken(user);
            }

            return BadRequest(new { message = $"Email claim not received from: {info.LoginProvider}" });
        }
        // If there is no record in AspNetUserLogins table, the user may not have
        // a local account
        else
        {
            // Get the email claim value
            var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

            if (email != null)
            {
                // Create a new user without password if we do not have a user already
                var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    user = new AppUser
                    {
                        UserName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email),
                        Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)
                    };

                    await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
                }

                // Add a login (i.e insert a row for the user in AspNetUserLogins table)
                await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                var userFromDb = await _context.Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role).FirstOrDefaultAsync(w => w.NormalizedEmail == email.ToUpper());
                return ReturnJwtToken(userFromDb);
            }

            return BadRequest(new { message = $"Email claim not received from: {info.LoginProvider}" });
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I found in console there is a problem with CORS:

Access to fetch at 'https://accounts.google.com...' (redirected from 'https://localhost:44309/api/AppUsers/authenticate/Google') from origin 'https://localhost:44309' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

But I specified this url in console.developers.google.com

[Authorized JavaScript origins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnKPB.png)

Comment: Did you manage to have it work? I need a sample app using dotnet core 3.1 React template with token based authentication. Would be glad if you can share your work on github.
Thanx

Comment: Hi @killjoy, Instead of fetch I create 'form' element: var form =                                     
                                    document.createElement('form');
                                    form.setAttribute('method', 'GET');
                                    form.setAttribute('action', 'api/AppUsers/authenticate/Google');
                                    document.body.appendChild(form);
                                    form.submit();

Comment: The ExternalLoginCallback is a call initiated by Google, and not your react app. Can I ask how ReturnJwtToken works, and how you transfer the user details to your react client?

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve CORS Policy error, I resolved it by adding below code in Stratup.cs

```
service.AddCors(opt =>{opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
    policy =>{policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();});});
```

You can also mention origins specifically
`AllowAnyOrigin` replace  to `WithOrigins("http://localhost:44309");`

But still stuck at sending the authentication response back to React can you add some inputs for me how you handled the particular scenario

Comment: I am also keen to know on transferring the auth response to the client. Have you managed to work it out?

Comment: I think for client side apps, the authorisation code flow is a better approach, in which the process is initiated by the client side, a code is sent to our .net core backend api, to be exchanged with the token and user information by calling google api on the backend. This way, as there is an active request between react and our api, the response (containing jwt) could be returned to the react app immediately. That possibly means GetExternalLoginInfoAsync would not be used in this process, at least for client side apps like react.

Comment: I think I have found one way to manage that, by putting the JWT into a cookie before redirect to a callback page, which will then read the JWT, and life goes back to normal auth afterwards.
Response.Cookies.Append("MyCookie", "cookieValue", cookieOptions);